# OpenStack Rally - is it possible to check nova console logs?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Openstack/Rally newbie here. In the basic Rally scenario for [boot_and_list.json](https://github.com/openstack/rally/blob/0.1.1/samples/tasks/scenarios/nova/boot-and-list.json), the boot operation simply [checks whether the VM reaches the "ACTIVE" state](https://github.com/openstack/rally/blob/master/rally/plugins/openstack/scenarios/nova/utils.py#L144).

However, in my organization, just because the VM has become "ACTIVE" does not mean that it has completely finished setting up all of our networking configuration. We would like to use Rally to benchmark the time it takes until a VM reaches a "Working" state, where "Working" is reached when a certain message is output into the nova console log. Currently our organization has set up a custom message to be printed out in the console log which indicates the state, such as "My image booted!" or "My image failed to boot: ". This way we can be confident that the VM is both "ACTIVE" and "Working."

Is there any existing way to use Rally to check some output in the nova console log? Perhaps by using the [`getConsoleOutput` API](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-compute-v2.1.html#getConsoleOutput)?

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [boot_and_get_sonsole_output](https://github.com/openstack/rally/blob/master/rally/plugins/openstack/scenarios/nova/servers.py#L779) method contains this exact funtionality, which was included with Rally [version 0.1.2](https://rally.readthedocs.org/en/latest/release_notes/archive/v0.1.2.html).

Since this is packaged in Rally now, users can use the [boot-and-get-console-server](https://github.com/openstack/rally/blob/master/samples/tasks/scenarios/nova/boot-and-get-console-server.json) scenario, editing the parameters to their needs.